# Laravel EBay API Client Credential Grant Request Gives Error, Unsupported Grant Type

Tags: laravel, ebay-api

I am using Laravel 8 and the Http Client library. Here is my code:

```
    public function mintNewApplicationAccessToken()
    {
        $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode(config('ebay.ebay_client_id_sandbox') . ":" . config('ebay.ebay_client_secret_sandbox')),
        ])->post(config('ebay.ebay_token_request_endpoint_url_sandbox'), [
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            'scope' => urlencode(config('ebay.ebay_client_credentials_scopes_sandbox')),
        ]);

        dd($response->json());
    }
```

I have double checked my client_id and client secret, I am using the Ebay sandbox at the moment, have checked the sandbox url is correct, I can't figure out what is wrong with my request? I get a 400 error back saying `unsupported_grant_type` and the error description says `grant type in request is not supported by the authorization server`. I have checked my scopes and everything seems in order?

Comment: are you sure its not supposed to be authorization_code? https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=5075

Comment: Im certain yes, its client_credentials for minting Application Access tokens. Its a slightly different flow for getting User Access Tokens, where you do need to use an authorization_code.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. As per the documentation on the Laravel website, I changed the code from:

```
    public function mintNewApplicationAccessToken()
    {
        $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode(config('ebay.ebay_client_id_sandbox') . ":" . config('ebay.ebay_client_secret_sandbox')),
        ])->post(config('ebay.ebay_token_request_endpoint_url_sandbox'), [
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            'scope' => urlencode(config('ebay.ebay_client_credentials_scopes_sandbox')),
        ]);

        dd($response->json());
    }
```

To:

```
        $auth = base64_encode(config('ebay.ebay_client_id_sandbox') . ':' . config('ebay.ebay_client_secret_sandbox'));

        $response = Http::asForm()->withOptions([
            'debug' => true,
        ])->withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . $auth,
        ])->post(config('ebay.ebay_token_request_endpoint_url_sandbox'), [
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
        'scope' => config('ebay.ebay_client_credentials_scopes_sandbox'),
        ]);

        dd($response->json());
```

So. I added asForm to the code rather than the Content-Type line, and removed the url encode from the scopes.

What surprised me most was when I removed the url encode method from the scopes it started working? Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

i have also same this problem and solution is that your account is not `veriyfied` or still waiting for `aproval` kindly contact support.

Comment: Hello, yes I just checked my account is already verified so that can't be the problem.